# How to use multiple Http Requests in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, api, typescript

I'm making a simple app with Angular 4 & an API who has several pages for their requests.

For example I get the 10 first characters with this url : 
`http://swapi.co/api/people/`

And to get the next 10 people I have to make request to this url : `http://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2`

How can I get all people in one request ? Or what is the solution to make all requests with good practices ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe why deleting the code and when I'm saying 'thanks' ?

Comment: Because including an answer and saying 'thanks' *isn't a question*. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for appropriate things to do when your question gets answered.

Comment: I thought the code could help people in this case. And the "thank by advance" means thanks for people who will work on this problem, it was not related to an answer. But ok

Comment: Just a comment, but shouldn't the data be loaded async on page change?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use `forkJoin` method in order to load data from more than one source.

First of all, include them in the `typescript` file.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

**UPDATE**

For new versions of Angular use this:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
```

Many times, we need to load data from more than one source, and we need to wait until all the data has loaded.

`forkJoin` method wraps multiple `Observables`. In the other words, we use `forkJoin` to run `concurrent` http **requests**.

`subscribe()` method of `forkJoin` sets the handlers on the entire set of **Observables**.

You can read more about **forkJoin** [here](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables-and-concurrent-data-loading), including a lot of examples.

Suppose you have to get first 10 pages.

```
var pages:number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

Or simply: `var pages:number[] = new Array(10).fill().map((v, i) => i + 1);`

```
// map them into a array of observables and forkJoin
return Observable.forkJoin(
   pages.map(
      i => this.http.get('http://swapi.co/api/people/?page=' + i)
        .map(res => res.json())
   )
).subscribe(people => this.people = people);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question with your suggestions.

Comment: @QuentinIcky, the mistake is that you use second `map` method wrong. Second `map` method is attached to the `this.http.get..`. (like in my answer)

Comment: Thanks that's right! I edited the question with the new code. I don't get any error, but now the people disappear from the view. How can I log the response and use the data to the component file ?

Comment: @QuentinIcky, i edited directly in your question. Have a look now.

Comment: I tried this too but I get ` Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.` 
I made others requests using the .subscribe in the component file without get an error. I don't understand why I get this now

Comment: @QuentinIcky, I found the mistake.. use `return Observable.forkJoin` instead `Observable.forkJoin`

Comment: Well done ! I understood that it was a `return` issue but I didn't found where ! Thanks al lot for your help!